# Change Play 2.0 from Java default to Scala

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, osx-mountain-lion

The [`Play Framework` site](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaTodoList) has a basic tutorial on how to create a simple scala application. The first step is to type `play new todolist` and then the system is supposed to prompt me to enter application name and then to choose either `Java`, `Scala`, or `Empty`. The problem is that the system does not prompt me to choose among `Java`, `Scala`, or `Empty`. I have both `Java` and `Scala` installed on my computer.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem so that I can decide which language to use? Right now it defaults to Java. My mac is `OSX Mountain Lion`.

Answer (score 3):

You set it in `project/Build.scala`. You need to change the line the says `mainLang = JAVA` to `mainLang = SCALA`.

Comment: Where would I find `project/Build.scala`?

Comment: In the root of the project directory.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right play version? play 1.x doesnt hve that project directory.